# Java: WeakReference.get() not returning null

Tags: java

I'm new to WeakReferences, so I'm just trying to understand this. I threw together this short snippet of code to test their behavior. I plan to use them in a project I'm working on, because I need to track references to objects on a temporary basis. ie, I want to have a reference to them in a collection so long as they're not being used anywhere else.

So far, though, this short test code sample hasn't been working like I want it to. No matter how long I wait, weakRef.get() always returns the value, it never returns null.

Please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    String s = "Hello World!";

    WeakReference<String> weakRef = new WeakReference<>(s);
    System.out.println("Original1: " + s);
    System.out.println("Weak1: " + weakRef.get());

    s = null;

    Thread.sleep(10000);

    Runtime.getRuntime().gc();

    int count = 0;
    while(weakRef.get() != null){
        System.out.println("Not null " + count);
        count++;
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    System.out.println("Null");
}
```

Edit: Updated my code sample. I even tried manually invoking the garbage collector, and the the final println still outputs "Weak2: Hello World!".

Edit 2: Changed it again. Moved the 10 second wait to before the garbage collection, then included the loop. The loop keeps running so far for 48 seconds (before I decided to close it) after the garbage collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java, string literals, like your `"Hello, World!"` are "interned"; that is, they are put in a cache for reuse. As long as a loaded class depends on one of these interned strings, it won't be reclaimed by the garbage collector, and that is what's preventing your `WeakReference` from being cleared. Try this instead:

```
WeakReference<String> weakRef = new WeakReference<>(new String(s));
```

Of course, a string that isn't assigned from a literal value in your source code—for example, a `String` created from file contents—will be garbage collected at an appropriate time. You just picked a subtly tricky example to test.

Comment: It says I can accept this answer in three minutes, but there's a decent change I'll forget. Just wanted to say that this was excellent, thank you so much.

Comment: *"That is, they are put in a cache, and not garbage collected"*.  It is more complicated than that.  The string pool cache is garbage collected (it uses weak references), but there is a strong reference from the code object(s) that use the literal to the String object.  That strong references keeps the literal in the cache ... unless the class gets unloaded.

Comment: @StephenC True, the exact details are more complicated. But a superficial explanation is sufficient to solve this problem.